# Prevent custom UITableViewCell from duplicating

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with an WishInfoTextView, just a subclass of UILabel.

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 NSMutableDictionary* item = [myWishes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

WishTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
if( cell == nil ) {
    cell = [[WishTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
    [cell setWishInfo: item];
}    

WishInfoTextView* infoText = (WishInfoTextView*)[cell viewWithTag: kTableInfoText];
infoText.text = [item objectForKey:@"name"];

NSLog(@"\nTaggedText: %@\nNormalText: %@", infoText.wishName, [item objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

Only the problem is that i have duplicated cells. I read something about setting tags.
But if i access my label by his tag, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `objectForKey@"name"` every time you want a cell. So you will always get the same thing. If you have an array of strings, use something like `[arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` in order to actually get different values.

For example, when I populate a table from an array I use

```
NSArray *nameSection = [appD.data objectForKey:key];
cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`appD.data` is gotten by

```
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Primary.plist"];
NSDictionary *data = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
```

Where `Primary.plist` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>First type</key>
    <array>
        <string>object1</string>
        <string>object2</string>
        <string>object3</string>
    </array>
    <key>Second type</key>
    <array>
        <string>thing1</string>
        <string>thing2</string>
        <string>thing3</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSMutableDictionary* item = [myWishes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]; sorry this part fell out of the code block. So thats not the problem

Comment: Is that what you're using? It all depends on the structure of your plist

Comment: Because that's the opposite order from my example

Comment: i have an array with dictionary objects. The first 4 tableviewcells are showing the right data, but the fifth shows the data from the first cell

Comment: How many cells can you see at once? It's probably a cell reuse problem

Comment: 2,5 i have an navigationbar and tabbar

Comment: what does 2,5 mean? Do you mean 2 and a half?

Comment: The problem is probably that, because `WishInfoTextView` is an object, once you set its label it stays the same upon reuse. Why aren't you just using `cell.textLabel.text`? Adding custom objects makes things much harder to fix.

Comment: because i use a NSAttributedString to highlight parts of the text and i draw it with core text

Comment: Okay then the best solution is probably to create an array of WishInfoTextViews and give each of them the right label. Then just programmatically put it in the table cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: But the wishinfotextviews are in my custom cell. So everytime i create a cell, i have to push the WishInfoTextView in to an array?

Comment: i fixed it. Because i used core text, i had to redraw the view using setNeedsDisplay so the text was updated again:) thanks for your help